# ACE automatic inheritance

Tags: inheritance, vbscript, acl

I want to add an ACE to a registry key but it is not inherited thru childs. Here is the VBScript code:

```
Set sdUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
S = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XXXX"
Set sd = sdUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(S, ADS_PATH_REGISTRY, ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID)
Set oldDacl = sd.DiscretionaryAcl
Set dacl = CreateObject("AccessControlList")
dacl.AclRevision = ADS_REVISION_DS
dacl.AceCount = 0
'remove network service ace if it exists
For Each ace In oldDacl
    If UCase(ace.trustee) <> "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" And UCase(ace.trustee) <> "S-1-5-20" Then
        ace.AceFlags = ace.AceFlags Or OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE Or CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE
        dacl.AddAce ace
    End If
Next
'add the new network service ace
Set ace = CreateObject("AccessControlEntry")
ace.Trustee = "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
ace.AccessMask = KEY_ALL_ACCESS 
ace.AceFlags = OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE Or CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE
ace.AceType = ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_ALLOWED
dacl.AddAce ace
If (sd.Control And SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERITED) <> 0 Then
    sd.Control = sd.Control Or SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ
End If
If (sd.Control And SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERITED) <> 0 Then
    sd.Control = sd.Control Or SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ
End If
If (sd.Control And SE_DACL_PROTECTED) <> 0 Then
    sd.Control = sd.Control Xor SE_DACL_PROTECTED
End If
ReorderDacl dacl 'This subroutine reorder dacl using w2k rules
sd.DiscretionaryAcl = dacl 
ret = sdUtil.SetSecurityDescriptor(S, ADS_PATH_REGISTRY, sd, ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID)
```

I also use another routine that scans all children keys and removed all ACEs except those marked as ADS_ACEFLAG_INHERITED_ACE

After code executes I get that childs of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XXXX only inherit SYSTEM, Administrators, Everyone & Restricted accesses. They are set on the parent key, but the NETWORK SERVICE access is on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XXXX but not propagated to the childs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got that already existing child keys do not get the inherited ace automatically so I had to, manually and recursively, add the ace to all childs with the ADS_ACEFLAG_INHERITED_ACE or'ed.

Although documentation says that ADS_ACEFLAG_INHERITED_ACE is set by the system, one can set it manually too.